# Как у блока с position:fixed менять цвет при прохождении определенной границы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно чтобы при прокрутке страницы на синем фоне он был красным, а на красным был синим

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="fixed"></div>
  <div class="block red"></div>
  <div class="block blue"></div>
  <div class="block red"></div>
  <div class="block blue"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: А если на границе окажется?

Comment: В середине границы вообще идеально было бы

Answer (score 2):

```js
function onScroll() {
  const back = document.elementFromPoint(10, 100);
  const className = (back.classList.contains('red')) ? 'blue' : 'red';
  const fix = document.querySelector('.fixed');
  if (!fix.classList.contains(className)) {
    fix.classList.remove('red', 'blue');
    fix.classList.add(className);
  }
}

onScroll();
window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="fixed"></div>
  <div class="block red"></div>
  <div class="block blue"></div>
  <div class="block red"></div>
  <div class="block blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хотел бы узнать подробнее о elementFromPount, он случайно не считает координаты блока сразу всех?  Ибо это был как пример, а в реальном проекте у меня разная высота блока и привязать именно к координатам не получится

Comment: @Павел он возвращает объект, который находится в указанных координатах. Никакую высоту он не считает

Answer (score 1):

А вот решение с динамической границей

```js
function onScroll() {
  const fix = document.querySelector('.fixed');
  const rectFix = fix.getBoundingClientRect();
  const back = document.elementFromPoint(rectFix.x - 1, rectFix.y);
  const rectBack = back.getBoundingClientRect();
  const topHeight = rectBack.bottom - rectFix.y;
  const backClass = (back.classList.contains('red')) ? 'red' : 'blue';
  const otherClass = (backClass === 'red') ? 'blue' : 'red';
  const fixTop = fix.querySelector('.top');
  fixTop.style.height = (topHeight < rectFix.height) ? (topHeight + "px") : "100%";
    
  if (!fixTop.classList.contains(otherClass)) {
    fixTop.classList.remove('red', 'blue');
    fixTop.classList.add(otherClass);
    const fixBottom = fix.querySelector('.bottom');
    fixBottom.classList.remove(otherClass);
    fixBottom.classList.add(backClass);
  }
}

onScroll();
window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fixed .bottom {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="fixed">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block red"></div>
  <div class="block blue"></div>
  <div class="block red"></div>
  <div class="block blue"></div>
</div>
```